# Dividing data -cache

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, intersystems-cache

[report][image: 1]

the attached code shows the result of each ward and it works well. I want just to divide the 5c ward into two wards in the report while it is one ward in the system. this ward is a mixed ward(5c) and I want to calculate the beds differently. I want to separate the beds of the 5c ward into two wards (5c-pediatric which has the first 6 beds of 5c and 5c-surgery which has the last 6 beds of 5c). I tried but I could not.

the the below shows each ward data. the desired report is to divide only 5c ward into 2 wards, we differeante the beds by the name if the bed name has pediatric means belong to pediatric and if the bed name has surgey means the bed belong to surgey

[the output of report][image: 2]

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output, also how do you distinguish different beds in 5c ward?

Comment: i added the requested data

Comment: Your table shows 24 beds in 5C, but you say the first 6 as pediatric, and the last 6 as a surgery, which means that supposed to be just only 12 beds. And anyway, you did not show original data in the table, just some report, which contains different information and gathered in your code.

Comment: how can i divide the ward in the cursor I tried but I could not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more related to the internal InterSystems TrakCare structures rather than general SQL. Given the query you have you can't divide a ward into two because your query will return ward IDs and all further processing is done inside `GetTotalRegular` and `ProcessData` procedures presumably based on current ward ID. So you need to look into what those procedures are doing and in case of ward `5C` process bed data into two rows or temporary globals rather than just one.